# gdb debug->watch: print array values in single line

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-code, debugging, watch

Watch section in debug window allows to cast pointers to different type. For example it is possible to cast structure of arrays to type[dim1]\[dim2] This is useful for displaying memory using specific type for example short int. Cast variable can be expanded in watch window to show components - for example *(short[2][4]) va* will expand 2D array of 16 bit signed integers to:

```
  [0] 
    >[0]: int16_0
    >[1]: int16_1 
    >[2]: int16_2 
    >[3]: int16_3
  [1] 
    >[0]: int16_4
    >[1]: int16_5 
    >[2]: int16_6 
    >[3]: int16_7
```

For longer multidim arrays this takes up a lot of room in debug watch window. Is it possible to display values same way as through gdb in debug window:

```
-exec print/d (va[2][4]) va $4 = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

Such format would be read-only and not allow modification but for displaying vector registers in Neon or SSE is really handy. It could be all values between curly brackets as in gdb or two expanded curly brackets:

```
{{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

or

```
[0]: {0, 1, 2, 3} 
[1]: {4, 5, 6, 7}
```

VS code document has section about writing custom handlers for debug. Maybe there is a simpler existing method to accomplish this?

I did try to use format specifiers for watch expressions but did not find such field.